# How to get number of locks acquired by my MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, update, locking

How to get number of locks acquired by my `MySQL` update query?

Is it possible using `MySQL Command Prompt` or `MySQL Workbench`?

**Example query** : `update employees set store_id = 0 where store_id = 1;`

Comment: And what will you do with the knowledge of the number of locks?

Comment: Hi I need to improve the performance by locking strategy using isolation level of database. I have changed isolation level but I could not able to view the impact of it.

Comment: If that 'example query' hits one row and `store_id` is indexed, then the query will be so fast that locks, etc, won't matter.  If, on the other hand, it hits a million rows, then let's discuss how to rewrite the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per info linked in comment - it needs some preparing, cannot probably be used automatically:
that is output from

```
show engine innodb status
```

You can see it if you do in commandline:

```
begin;
update employees set store_id = 0 where store_id = 1;
```

and then in any (even the same) session

```
show engine innodb status\G
```

Where you look for section labeled

```
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
```

and find transaction which the update is part of.

Original answer (still holds for general usage IMHO)
I don't think it is possible directly, but you can get some details about locks from server status:

```
show session status like 'Innodb_%_lock%';
```

if you run it before and after query, you can check difference and analyze it.

Comment: It should be possible as I have read [this](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/08/28/differences-between-read-committed-and-repeatable-read-transaction-isolation-levels) article and it seems that he has given analysis of number lock acquired by update query.

Comment: Check updated answer @VishalZanzrukia